# SATA drive validation

Tags: scripting, sata, verification

I am trying to validate a drive that supports secure erase in multiple formats.  The format is specified in a vendor specific ATA-8 packet.  Our technician has solved the issue quite ingeniously by using the protocol tester drivemaster to create a packet "close" to the one needed and then using the error injection function of a SATA analyzer to modify the packet to the correct format.

Now the customer is asking for a Linux utility so that they can test the functionality.  I would of course prefer a more straight forward method to test vendor specific commands in the future as well.

In general I was wondering if there is a utility in Linux that I could use for drive validation on drives by exercising the protocol directly (ATA, SATA etc.).

If this type of support is built into a scripting language (python or perl etc.) then maybe just a little advice as to what language has the best support under Linux for this type of effort. That would save me time researching the best path to take.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which sort of "validation" you are thinking of. Do you want to test on a data integrity-related issue, or do you want to check its health or would you want to work with the drive directly?

For some immediate ideas that might help:
The package `gsmartcontrol` is a front-end to `smartmontools` package, which contains the `smartctl` CLI tool for dealing primarily with a drive's SMART features, including reporting, logging and self-tests.

`hdparm` is the first tool that comes to my mind if you speak of dealing with hard drives directly. It can issue a range of direct S/ATA commands to the drive, bypassing the usual Linux driver. The features include getting drive information/identification (from the device itself), reading and setting multiple sector count (IDE Block Mode), reading contents of specific sectors directly from disk and setting the device's power state (e.g. cause it to spin down immediately), among others.

If this is not what you're looking for, please also clarify in the question.

### Something at all sensible to add?

*The next content makes this quite a low-quality "answer"*

Because the request is so low-level (see comment), I'm just adding a few potentially interesting links, as I am not aware of any common user-space software exists for what is basically low-level hardware testing. Have done a bit of a search and found the following that might be useful if writing custom software needs to be done here:

***Note that all these resources are around the 2.6 kernel, which is about 16 years old!***

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch14.html "The Linux Device Model"

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch16.html "

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/ioctl/hdio.html gives a summary explanation of kernel (v2.6) HDIO functions, mentioned in the previous article.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/data-integrity.html

This is all I can give, without any personal experience in this field and more specific info (e.g. is it actually a hard drive or an SDD?).

Comment: Thanks for the response,  by validation I mean validating that the design meets the customer specifications as in DVT (Design Validation Test).  I am looking for something a little more low level then what I saw in hdparm and smartmontools.  I am testing the correctness of the drive's response to the protocol, one level below most of the information I am finding on the net.

Comment: That is a very low-level interaction there. I have never seen user software lingering in repositories that does something like directly managing the disk through controller commands -- this is normally done around device driver development, hence the link to kernel.org. I also haven't found a distribution that is geared towards such things; this is not a general recovery or "forensics" question anyway (unless it is specialised forensic recovery that'd cost thousands to perform). You may have to write some custom software to do the testing for you if `hdparm` and `sdparm` don't do it.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, it is actually more helpful then  you are implying in your comments.  I was kind of hoping that an API existed that you could access from a script to customize protocol testing.  I realize I'm casting kind of a wide net for information.